Spring Webfilter class does not work in Spring WebFlux application after upgrading from Spring Boot 2.7.x to 3.2.x
We have a filter in our Spring WebFlux application, as shown below
public class MyFilter implements WebFilter {
   @Override
   public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain) 
      {
        ...
      }
}

The filter was working when we are using Spring Boot version 2.7.10.
Recently, we upgraded from Spring Boot version 2.7.18 to Spring Boot version 3.2.6. The filter is not getting invoked after the Spring Boot upgrade.
We have below two dependencies in our pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>

The filter is triggered if I remove the dependency spring-boot-starter-web, but the API call is returning 404 in this case.
If I re-add the spring-boot-starter-web dependency, then the API is working but the filter is not triggered.

Actually are you using webflux or web? Both of them are different approach. Simple question: are you using blocking or nonblocking io? Reactive or servlet?

If you are using both at the same time, I couldnt imagine :)

You have embedded tomcat and netty at the same time. Just decide one of the dependency

Imho just investigate that why it gives 404

After removing dependency spring-boot-starter-web and changing below property in our application
from (removed)
server.servlet.context-path=/myapp

to (added)
spring.webflux.base-path=/myapp

